# condition matching in an array with case class in scala

Tags: scala

I have a task need to find a particular string in an array:
     1. if found, return its value;
     2. if not found, return -1.

I wrote an "idea" code, but I don't know how to finish it correctly.

```
case class person(name:String, value: Int)
personList[Array[person]]

val result = personList match { 
case x if x.name == "john" => x.value
case _ => -1 }
```

the complier reports errors at "`case x if x.name`"

Comment: If found return value, i.e. `String`. If not found return -1, i.e. `Int`. That doesn't sound right. `String` and `Int` are different types.

Comment: Sorry, changed it to Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
persons.find(_.name == "john").fold(-1)(_.value)
```

Note: I've left the creation and/or population of the `persons` array up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = personList.find(_.name=="john") match { 
case some(x) => x.value
case None => -1 }
```